# Using a geopoint property in Azure IOT Central

Tags: python, azure-iot-central

I'm using the IOTC firmware (through python).I have been able to upload location data as telemetry. However I have not been able to upload location data as a basic property. Is this possible?

- Since my device isn't supposed to move around I wasn't planning on sending telemetry location. I would prefer just to send the location once as a device property when the device boots and connects to Azure IOT Central.
- The location datatype is GeoPoint which enables to plot it on a map in Azure IOT Central.

I'm formatting my JSON like this

```
{"location":{"lon":3.837585, "lat":41.174130}}
```

I have also tried this

```
{"location":{"value": {"lon":3.837585, "lat":41.174130}}}
```

The answer from Roman below shows that it is possible to do it through the MQTT API. But I would like to do it through the Azure iot central firmware with Python.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to make a Location property. The following screen snippets show this example with a simple PnP template:

1. create the custom template with one Location property:

[image]

2. Assign the template to the real device (in my test is the *device100*) and then process its registering and provisioning. For testing purpose I am using my [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester):

[image]

As the above picture shows, the reported property has the **following format**:

```
{
  "Location":{
    "value":{
      "lat":41.17413,
      "lon":3.837585
    }
  }
}
```

Publishing the above reported property to the IoT Central, we can see the *Location* on the dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roman! That looks to prove that it is indeed possible to put a Geopoint in a Location property on a map :) That looks to point to the IOTC firmware of which I'm using the python flavor has an issue (Or I'm doing something wrong :)).
I'm looking for a way to do it from Python.